# Get the text of a JButton using a Action Listener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Is there a reason why `getText` causes an `error: cannot find symbol` inside the action listener shown in the code? Also if there is, how would I fix this error?

```
class openNewPaneActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String butSrcTxt = e.getSource().getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you add this listener to your component.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a nice and simple trick you can use...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String butSrcTxt = e.getActionCommand();
}
```

If you do not specify the `actionCommand` for a button, then the `text` of the button is used instead.

Now, if you do specify the `actionCommand` property for the button AND you still want to know the text (which seems weird to me) you could use something more like...

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton)source;
        String butSrcTxt = btn.getText();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have a question for you @MadProgrammer, I have images stored on a folder in my server and it's location stored in my database, I want to retrieve these images with java code with Inputstream but I've no idea how to carry it out, could you help?

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb Does your client program have direct access to your server, maybe via a network drive?  If not, you will need some kind of process (web server/socket/ftp) on the server which you connect to (from your client) and download said file

Comment: Through SQL yes, I think, because I am trying to download the image and store it in an object, then retrieve the object later and display it with a JPanel

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb But if the image is stored in the sever (and not in the database), then you can't use SQL to retrieve them, the best it can do is tell you "where" they are stored, you need some other mechanism to look those files up and send them to you

Comment: Well I was looking up InputStream to see if it would solve my problem, no such luck :(

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb Generally speaking, you need some kind of access the server (like a network share) or some service on the server (like a web service, socket or ftp) which you can use to read the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98038/discussion-between-programming-newb-and-madprogrammer).